# Optimal way to get the maximum list of events one can attend

Tags: ruby, algorithm

For the problem, the input is an array like this:
[[4,8],[1,3],[7,9],[5,6]]
where the first number of every element represents the start hour and the second number the end hour.

What is the optimal way to get the maximum list of events one can attend?

My approach was:

1. Sort the array in ascending order by start hour
2. Iterate trough every element from last to first and check if they overlap (start hour of the current element is lower than the end hour of the element at the left).
3. If there is an overlap, remove the left element and check again

The code is:

```
def time_schedule(ar)
  #Assuming the ar has been sorted    
  idx = input.length - 1
  while idx >= 1
    while idx >= 1 && input[idx - 1][1] > input[idx][0]
      input.delete(input[idx - 1])
      idx -= 1
    end
    idx -= 1
  end    
  input
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is close, but wrong.  Because you can run into a long event when you could have accepted multiple small ones.

Instead sort ascending by **end hour**.  Accept each event that does not overlap with any accepted before it.

Comment: I don't doubt your claim but your answer could be improved by providing.a proof (by contradiction, I would suggest).